# PHP if statement if the page was loaded with ajax

Tags: php, jquery

I have a page that loads with a div populated from an include file (pullList.php), but if you click a button (let's say a "re-load" button) the content of the div is reloaded with that same file (pullList.php).

The problem now is that when the page is loaded via ajax (with jquery) I need an include file (function.php) inside the pullList.php file which is already included on the page.

So, ideally I'd like to be able to write a statement that says

```
if(the page was loaded with ajax) {
       include(function.php);
}
```

That way the function.php file will only be loaded once, and if the page is requested again via ajax, it has the right functions to display the content properly.

I've tried using include_once, but didn't work - had the same problem. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
  include(function.php);
}
```

Comment: you should use `isset`, not `empty`

Comment: @Petah: why is this? I always through that `empty` is the same as `isset` but it also checks if there is a value?

Comment: @JohnMagnolia donno, I was either too noob back then or had a good reason I have since forgot.

Answer (score 6):

```
function isAjax() {
    return (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && 
        ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest'));
}
```

Source : http://snipplr.com/view/1060/check-for-ajax-request/

Answer (score 2):

Check the $_SERVER["HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH"] contained xmlhttprequest